# GNU Make: "dir not expected at this moment"

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a  makefile including the following lines:

```
buildrepo:
    @$(call make-repo)

define make-repo
   for dir in $(C_SRCS_DIR); \
   do \
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$$dir; \
   done
endef
```

On the line with the commands `for dir in $(C_SRCS_DIR); \` I get the following error message:

```
"dir not expected at this moment"
make: *** [buildrepo] Error 255
```

I am using `GNU make`.

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: This WORKSFORME. What is the output of `$(INFO SHELL = $(SHELL))`

Answer (score 1):

Actually this `for ... in ... ; do ... done` statement is a Unix command not a GNU make command, therefore I guess you are using a Windows machine (or any other one). You have to find the equivalent for your system.

But GNU make has a foreach function which works like this :

```
$(foreach dir,$(C_SRCS_DIR),mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)/$(dir);)
```

Also note that in your very specific case (not related to GNU make but to Windows) you can create all the dirs without a for/foreach loop, just like this :

```
mkdir -p $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(C_SRCS_DIR))
```

Comment: Usually, even if `$(addprefix)` doesn't work, you can still use `$(patsubst)`.